# UpdateRequest SOAP request returns Bad Request

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap

I am using the Marketing Cloud SOAP API to update some data within my Data Extension using the following payload.

Header:

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: myserverid.soap.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPaction: Update
```

Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
   <fueloauth>MYKEYGOESHERE</fueloauth>
 </s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions>
        <SaveOption>
          <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
          <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
        </SaveOption>
      </SaveOptions>
      <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
    </Options>
    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <CustomerKey>MYDEKEY</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>subscriberkey</Name>
            <Value>TestSubscriberKey123</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>mobilenumber</Name>
            <Value>08123456798</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>firstname</Name>
            <Value>Janet</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>lastname</Name>
            <Value>Doe 123</Value>
          </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
</s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

However I get a Bad Request error.

EDIT: Updated payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
   <fueloauth>MYSECRETKEY</fueloauth>
 </s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions>
        <SaveOption>
          <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
          <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
        </SaveOption>
      </SaveOptions>
      <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
    </Options>
    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <CustomerKey>MYDEKEY</CustomerKey>
        <Keys>
            <Key>
                <Name>subscriberkey</Name>    
                <Value>TestSubscriberKey123</Value>
            </Key>
        </Keys>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>subscriberkey</Name>
            <Value>TestSubscriberKey123</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>mobilenumber</Name>
            <Value>08123456798</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>firstname</Name>
            <Value>Janet</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>lastname</Name>
            <Value>Doe 123</Value>
          </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
</s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing the 'keys' node for this envelope:

```
<Keys>
    <Key>
        <Name>Subscriberkey</Name>    
        <Value>mySubkeyValue</Value>
    </Key>
</Keys>
```

Which should be above the 'Properties' node like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options>
            <SaveOptions>
               <SaveOption>
                  <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
                  <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
               </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
           </Options>
          <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
          <CustomerKey>MYDEKEY</CustomerKey>
          <Keys>
              <Key>
                  <Name>Subscriberkey</Name>    
                  <Value>TestSubscriberKey123</Value>
              </Key>
          </Keys>
          <Properties>
              <Name>mobilenumber</Name>
              <Value>08123456798</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Name>firstname</Name>
              <Value>Janet</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Name>lastname</Name>
              <Value>Doe 123</Value>
            </Property>
          </Properties>
          </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The keys are needed to be able to define what is a new record (add) and what is an edit to an existing record (update).

**EDIT** - I added in the full, working SOAP envelope I used for reference in hopes that some part of it might be the missing piece you need to solve your 'Bad Request' error.

Comment: I have tried this, still seems to be getting Bad Requests, I have even tried removing `subscriberkey` property out of the `<Properties>` section as its used as the `<Key>` but this still returns the same error.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure - You definitely want to remove the subscriberkey out of properties if it is the key. Try changing 'SOAPAction' in header to 'SoapAction'. Not 100% positive, but I think that is case-sensitive.

Comment: Tried switching to `SoapAction`, this has also returned the same response error.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure - I'll be honest, I don't really know why it would still be tossing that error. Maybe its something with the defining of the Envelope Header and/or Body. I am going to add these into my answer for reference (as it works correctly on my end) and maybe utilizing those will assist in debugging what the heck it is causing your issue.

Comment: If you could update your answer with the body and header, I'll just try replicating with that.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure - Already added into answer. Should be second code block